# Getting illegal invocation, after using $.ajax inside of $(doocument).keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically, I want to save the user keystrokes to my database. So, for 10 key presses, after they cross  ten keys then I have that into database. I appended the keys, but got an issue. The issue was when using $.ajax, it says illegal invocation.

```
var url = window.location;
window.collectedData = [
    {
        type: 'key',
        data: ''
    },
    {
        type: 'mouse',
        data: []
    }
];

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;  // Get the Unicode value
    var y = String.fromCharCode(x);
    collectedData[0].data += y;

    if (collectedData[0].data.length > 10) {
        let data_ = collectedData[0].data;
        let type_ = collectedData[0].type;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/track",
            type: 'post',
            csrf: token,
            data: {
                url: url,
                item: type_,
                data: data_
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`illegal invocation` is usually caused when you pass a non plain object to $.ajax data parameter.

`window.location` is not a string rather a Location object, you should use `window.location.href` instead.